# Qml TextEdit Custom key event not processed properly

Tags: qt, qml

I wanted to add custom key events to a `TextEdit`. But, it seems key events are not properly processed inside `TextEdit`.

For example, in the code below, I am trying to handle `Space` key events. Although the `Space` keypress is recognized by the signal handler function, the output text does not contain a space. It is the same for all other key events. How do I overcome this?

```cpp
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Item{

    function processSpace(event){
        event.accepted = true
        console.log(xTextEdit.text)
    }

    TextEdit{
        id: xTextEdit
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width
        Keys.onSpacePressed: processSpace(event)
    }
}
```

Comment: You accept the event, thus prevent the default handling. Try to set `event.accepted = false` instead

Comment: @king_nak, why didnt you put it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: I was not sure it works, and had no time to test it myself. But put it as an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accept the event, and thus prevent the default handling.

Set `event.accepted = false` instead, so the event will be propagated.

Note that accepted is by default `true` (at least for key events), so not setting it will the accept the event